# Working with asynchronous data with Swift closures and Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

I need to call a specific Firebase reference and get back data. This operation will take place inside multiple VCs so I want to have a class where I will have various functions calling Firebase. For example, if I want to get all articles I will call my FirebaseHelpers class, and use the method/closure **fetchArticles()**. This way, if I want to refactor something I will only do it in FirebaseHelpers class, and not go through all VCs.

### FirebaseHelpers

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FirebaseHelpers {

    func fetchArticles(completion: @escaping ([Article]?, Error?) -> Void) {
            
        var articles = [Article]()

        let articlesQuery = Database.database().reference().child("articles").queryOrdered(byChild: "createdAt")

        articlesQuery.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let articlesDictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        
            articlesDictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
            
                guard let articleDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                // build articles array
                let article = Article(dictionary: articleDictionary)

                print("this is article within closure \(article)")
            
                articles.append(article)
            
            })
        
        })

        completion(articles, nil)
    }
}
```

### In any viewController

```
let firebaseHelpers = FirebaseHelpers()

var articles = [Article]() {
    didSet {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

// this is inside viewDidLoad()
firebaseHelpers.fetchArticles { (articles, error) in
        
    guard let articles = articles else { return }
        
    print("articles \(articles)")
        
    self.articles = articles
}
```

The problem is that I don't get any results back. In my VC the print("articles (articles)") will return an ***empty array***. But in my FirebaseHelpers fetchArticles() the print("this is article within closure (article)") will print the article(s) ***just fine***.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move `completion` inside your asynchronous function:

```
class FirebaseHelpers {

    func fetchArticles(completion: @escaping ([Article]?, Error?) -> Void) {
            
        var articles = [Article]()

        let articlesQuery = Database.database().reference().child("articles").queryOrdered(byChild: "createdAt")

        articlesQuery.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let articlesDictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        
            articlesDictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
            
                guard let articleDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                // build articles array
                let article = Article(dictionary: articleDictionary)

                print("this is article within closure \(article)")
            
                articles.append(article)
            })
        
            completion(articles, nil) // <- move here
        })

        // completion(articles, nil) // <- remove
    }
}
```

Otherwise `completion` will be called before your asynchronous function.

Comment: Just when I started liking the whole closure thing! :) Thanks @pawello2222